# Robocopy destination folder not specified

Tags: windows, backup, robocopy

I want to make a backup copy of an entire drive to a folder in an external drive but `robocopy` doesn't "see" the specified destination folder.

The idea is to update all the files and add the new ones in the J drive every time I run this command. So the result will be a clone of the D drive at that moment.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
robocopy "D:\" "J:\2Tera" /copy:datso /mir /fft /r:0 /w:0 /secfix /mt:20 /xo /xf thumbs.db /log+:J:\TON-FS4.log /nc /ns /np /ndl /nfl /tee
```

Also, Do I need to add `/b` switch?

A couple of folder are windows backup folders in that drive.(D:)

Comment: Does robocopy "D:\" work? Notice the backslash.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean It seems like robocopy "sees" D:\" J:\2Tera"\ as source folder

Answer (score -1):

Quotation marks are not needed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1124305)

Comment: Why not? If he take the quotations it works.